# Where does Google Tasks tasks arrived from?

Tags: google-tasks

I recently installed [Google Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.tasks) and was surprised to find tasks and lists over there. I haven't used Google Tasks on the web (or from gmail) either.

Those were old tasks/notes taken around 3-6 years ago.
I checked my Google keep, Google reminders/assistant and Gmail (which are the platforms I use and used for reminders/notes/lists) and haven't found any origin for them.
(I rarely delete, I always archive, so if it existed in one of them it should've been found).

Where did they arrived from?

By [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams)' advice is I searched in my [Google activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) for phrases and tasks I had in the list, but I only found them in the search history, and not in any kind of task/list/note app.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Log into your Google account >[my activity](https://myactivity.google.com/my activity) and check. They should be available there. If you want to disable, go to activity controls from hamburger menu and do that.

Comment: Correct link - [My activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately it didn't yield a thing (updated the question)

Comment: +1. Hope you get an answer

Comment: AFAIR Google Mail has (or had?) the feature to automatically extract infos on tasks and appointments from your mails. May be the tasks were created automatically while you were using GMail?

Comment: It's sounds weird, and I really don't recall creating a task on Gmail. Specifically, those two terms were part of a list - so for sure it wasn't just a task

Answer (score 0):

Google tasks has been since long, but only in Gmail. [Here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-to-access-your-google-tasks/) is a 2009 article explaining it. 
I guess it came around the same time probably. There wasn't a separate app for it back then. It was just a chat-type window popup in the bottom of your gmail screen. Check the old Gmail, the tasks' list comes from the drop down in the top left (circled red)

[image]

Comment: I haven't used it, at least not regularly in a way that can explain the amount of tasks and lists I had. Some of them were created from mobile for sure.